# Trying to make a gui for my code. What did I do wrong?

Tags: python-2.7

For a while I was working on a code which would loop and add or subtract by 1 everytime I chose the right option, also print for me the current number when I chose to do so. I'm now trying to make a gui on Tkinter out of it. Here is the original code:

```
students = 0

def addstudent():
    global students
    students = students + 1
    print "\n Student Added"
def subtractstudent():
    global students
    students = students - 1
    print "\n Student Deleted"
def checkstudentrec():
    print students
    print "\n Student Record Found"

ans=True
while ans:
    print ("""
    1.Add a Student
    2.Delete a Student
    3.Look Up Student Record
    4.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=raw_input("What would you like to do?")
    if ans=="1": 
        addstudent()
    if ans=="2":
        subtractstudent()
    if ans=="3":
        checkstudentrec()
```

GUI one that doesn't work:

```
from TKinter import *


class experiment:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.addbutton = Button(frame, text="Add Student", command=self.addstudent)
        self.addbutton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.subbutton = Button(frame, text="Subtract Student", command=self.subtractstudent)
        self.subbutton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.checkbutton = Button(frame,text="Check Record", command=self.checkstudentrec)
        self.checkbutton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame,text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

   def addstudent():
        global students
        students = students + 1
        print "\n Student Added"
      def subtractstudent():
         global students
         students = students - 1
         print "\n Student Deleted"
   def checkstudentrec():
        print students
        print "\n Student Record Found"

root = Tk()
students = 0
b = experiment(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/richjtf/PycharmProjects/project1/firstproject.py
File "/home/richjtf/PycharmProjects/project1/firstproject.py", line 8
frame.pack()
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The answer is In d question.Indentation error.correct it